# How to resolve this: "Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x105d25e88) to 'NSDictionary' (0x105d261a8)."

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am working with Firebase with the following structure:

[image: firebase structure here]

When i click on saved button, this is the code that writes to firebase:

```
let savedDB = Database.database().reference().child("saved")
let postid = detailpost?.postid
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let key = savedDB.child(postid!).key
let childUpdates : [String : String] = ["\(uid!)/\(key)/": "true"]
savedDB.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

To try to read the data, here's the code I have:

```
if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
     let savedDB = Database.database().reference().child("saved").child(uid)
     savedDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
     let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>
     if let savedpostid = snapshotValue["postid"]{
     ......
```

When I the code gets to this step it crashes, with the following error message:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x111688e88) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1116891a8).
```

I'm not able to figure out what causes this problem and how to resolve it. Can someone advice please? Thank you.

Comment: From your code and the error, it seems that `snapshot.value` is in fact a String, and not a Dictionary object.

Comment: Why would that be so? ["\(uid!)/\(key)/": "true"] results in ["String":"String"], wouldn't that be a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>
```

into this:

```
 let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! FIRDataSnapshot
```

check this link for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot

> A FIRDataSnapshot contains data from a Firebase Database location. Any time you read Firebase data, you receive the data as a FIRDataSnapshot.

Comment: It doesn't work as well, as i replaced it as advised, this error message pops up "Type 'DataSnapshot' has no subscript members" at this line of code: "if let savedpostid = snapshotValue["postid"]{ "

Comment: @Ben okay try this  `let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,String>` use optional as

Comment: Doesn't work as well, once i change to optional as?, in the next line I was prompted to unwrap snapshotValue, i.e. "if let savedpostid = snapshotValue!["postid"]{ ". Upon running the code, it crashes with the following error message: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself by changing the code to as follows:

```
if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
let savedDB = Database.database().reference().child("saved").child(uid)

savedDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
let savedpostid = snapshot.key
```

Thanks to folks for suggesting that the Dictionary is actually a String, which led me to the answer.